# Loading QLR file in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qlr, qgslayertree

I'm trying to load a qlr-file in QGIS 3.16 and zoom to a certain area using python:

```py
QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinition('E:/QGIS/test.qlr',QgsProject.instance(), QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot())
iface.mapCanvas().setCenter(QgsPointXY(712345,5123456))
iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(2200)
print ("done")
```

I would expect the loadLayerDefinition-command to be completed before the setCenter- and zoomScale-commands are executed.
But when I run this script with **no layer in the layertree** QGIS prints "done" (the last command) before it even starts to draw the loaded layer on the map and finally zooms to a full extent instead of zooming to the scale of '2200'.

How can I make QGIS to finish loading the qlr-file before continuing with the next command?

Answer (score 2):

I concur with your observations and tried a few approaches to solve the problem. I don't love this approach, but it does seem to work effectively.

The workaround is to connect the `mapCanvasRefreshed` signal, which will be emmitted when the canvas is redrawn *after* the layer definition file has been loaded, to a slot function which immediately disconnects the slot from from the signal (since the `mapCanvasRefreshed` signal is also fired on zooming, panning etc.), then sets the canvas center and zoom level.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()

filepath = 'E:/QGIS/test.qlr'

def set_scale():
    # disconnect the slot from the signal immediately
    iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.disconnect(set_scale)
    
    iface.mapCanvas().setCenter(QgsPointXY(712345,5123456))
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(2200)
    print ("done")


# connect set_scale function to mapCanvasRefreshed signal which will be emmitted
# when the canvas is redrawn **after** the layer definition file has been loaded
iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.connect(set_scale)

QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinition(filepath, project, project.layerTreeRoot())
```